# Collection class that maintains sorted order based on particular property?

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm looking for a collection class that will automatically insert elements in sorted order based on a property (namely "Priority"), so that when I iterate over it later, I'll get back the elements in this order.

---

[SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) seems to sort by keys, which is not what I want.

Comment: Did you try SortedDictionary<>?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx

Comment: @Harvey: Also sorts on key. I don't want a key.

Comment: This statement "SortedList seems to sort by keys, which is not what I want." and your question are contradictions. In order for any kind of sorted order to be imposed there has to be a comparison function (and hence a key to be compared)! Perhaps you want a FIFO queue?

Comment: @Mitch: I think we're confusing terms here. By "key" I'm referring to the thing you place in square brackets to retrieve an item; the indexer. I don't want one of those, that's basically a dictionary. It sounds like you're referring to a sort-key... yes, one of the properties will behave as a "key" to be sorted by, but you won't be able to retrieve the item with this value. If it helps, I'm looking for a `List` that is sorted by `value`.

Comment: @Mitch: SortedList and SortedDictionary are basically the same except in terms of performance, but neither of them are what I'm looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935621/whats-the-difference-between-sortedlist-and-sorteddictionary/935631#935631

Comment: @Ralph: I'm aware of all those things you mentioned...

Comment: @Mitch: Then you understand how it's not a contradiction?

Comment: @Ralph: I believe it is a contradiction. You implement IComparable, it uses Priority; Priority is your key field for sorting.

Comment: @Mitch: I feel like we're going in circles here. Yes, priority is the sort-key, but the "key" I'm referring to in the question is a dictionary-key. I want a sort-key, I don't want a dictionary-key. No contradiction.

Comment: @Ralph: It's your circle!! ;)

Comment: I know you have got your answer, but from the limited info you have given, it seemed you needed a `TreeBag<T>` from C5, or `OrderedBag<T>` from Power Collections. Passing an appropriate comparer would do. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196512/is-there-a-sorted-collection-type-in-net)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `SortedSet<T>`, which is new with .NET 4. You can use it on a class that implements `IComparable<T>` or you can provide an external comparer via a constructor overload. Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

class FooComparer : IComparer<Foo>
{
    public int Compare(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        // add null checking, demo purposes only
        return x.Bar.CompareTo(y.Bar);
    }
}
```

...

```
SortedSet<Foo> sortedFoos = new SortedSet<Foo>(new FooComparer());
sortedFoos.Add(new Foo() { Bar = 2 });
sortedFoos.Add(new Foo() { Bar = 1 });

foreach (Foo foo in sortedFoos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar);
}
// Prints 1, 2
```

**Note:** This collection behaves like a `HashSet<T>`. If you add multiple objects that compare equal, they will be discarded.

Comment: Seems like what I want. If I implement `IComparable` on the data type, I assume it'll use that?

Comment: Also, I assume that the sorting is "stable"? -- if two elements are inserted that compare equal, the first one will still be first in the set?

Comment: @Ralph, yes, it would support `IComparable<Foo>`. For more information, I would start with the MSDN documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx

Comment: @Ralph, caution! It looks like this behaves like a `HashSet<T>`, if two items compare equal, the second will be discarded. If you need multiple items with the same key property, you may have to consider another structure.

Comment: @Anthony: Yeah... the "key" property will be repeated, but the object as a whole ought to be unique. I guess it doesn't matter though if it only looks at the Compare function.

Comment: @Ralph, the `Compare` or `CompareTo` function does not need to only consider one property. You can use as many as you want as tie-breakers, but ultimately, you would need a way to differentiate between them.

Comment: @Anthony: Yeah...but I don't want tie-breakers. In case they have the same priority, I want it to be FIFO.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [`PriorityQueue`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). You can find several implementations in this similar question: [C# Priority Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937690/c-priority-queue).

Comment: Hehe...also my question :) Difference is, this time I don't need the priority separate.

Answer (score 1):

[C5 has an IntervalHeap](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) that does what I want.